# Subtract pairs of columns based on matching column

Tags: r, plyr

I'll apologise in advance - I know this has likely been answered elsewhere, but I don't seem to be able to find the answer I need, and can't manage to adapt other code I have found to my needs.

I have a data frame:

```
FILE | TECHNIQUE | COUNT
------------------------
A    | ONE       | 10
A    | TWO       | 25
B    | ONE       |  5
B    | TWO       | 30
C    | ONE       | 30
C    | TWO       | 50
```

I would like to produce a data frame of the difference of the COUNT values between ONE and TWO, with a row for each FILE, i.e.

```
FILE | DIFFERENCE
-----------------
A    |   15
B    |   25
C    |   20
```

I'm convinced I should be able to do this fairly easily with base R or Plyr, but am a bit stuck. Could anyone suggest a good way to do this, and perhaps good tutorials on Plyr that might help me with similar problems in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `aggregate` in base:

```
> aggregate(.~FILE, data= DF[, -2], FUN=diff)
  FILE COUNT
1    A    15
2    B    25
3    C    20
```

Using `ddply` in plyr

```
> ddply(DF[,-2], .(FILE), summarize, DIFFERENCE=diff(COUNT))
  FILE DIFFERENCE
1    A         15
2    B         25
3    C         20
```

with `data.table`

```
> # library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(DF)
> DT[, diff(COUNT), by=FILE]
   FILE V1
1:    A 15
2:    B 25
3:    C 20
```

with `by`

```
> with(DF, by(COUNT, FILE, diff))
FILE: A
[1] 15
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
FILE: B
[1] 25
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
FILE: C
[1] 20
```

with `tapply`

```
> tapply(DF$COUNT, DF$FILE, diff)
 A  B  C 
15 25 20
```

with `summaryBy` from doBy package

```
> # library(doBy)
> summaryBy(COUNT~FILE, FUN=diff, data=DF)
  FILE COUNT.diff
1    A         15
2    B         25
3    C         20
```

**Update**
As percentage:

```
> aggregate(.~FILE, data= DF[, -2], function(x) (x[1]/x[2])*100)
  FILE    COUNT
1    A 40.00000
2    B 16.66667
3    C 60.00000
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the fantastic answers and thanks for the variety - you're seriously on a roll (and I will accept your answer in a moment). One final addition - how could I calculate it as a percentage of the original? (e.g. A would become 40%). I understand this would involve using something other than diff, right?

Comment: where that 40% comes from?

Comment: Considering the 2 sample rows for FILE==A, COUNT for ONE = 10 and COUNT for TWO = 25, substitution gives (10/25)*100 = 40%.

If I use 'FUN=function(x){x}', I can get three columns in the result, from which I can calculate this, but this doesn't exactly seem the right way to do it.

Comment: I had literally just written the same code as your update (having used FUN=function(x){print(x); x} to see what x actually was. Thanks for the help - already accepted the answer, sorry I can't do much more!

Comment: `x` is each value belonging to each gruop: `A, B` and `C`.

Comment: What are you doing when you run out of options, offer solutions in different languages?!