# Grouping by two attributes and calculating the mean of another attribute in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to group by on "col1", "col2"  and get the mean of col3

```
newData
id    col1   col2    col3   col4   col5
1     200    2000    150     151    NA
2     200    2000    250     160   "tim"
3     201    2000    300     189    NA
4     201    2000    400     182    NA
```

I want my output to be

```
id    col1   col2    col3   col4    col5
1     200    2000    200     151     NA    
2     201    2000    350     189     NA

aggdata <-aggregate(newData, 
                by=list(newData$col1,newData$col2), 
                FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

this gives me the mean of all variables which I do not want.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with `col4` and `col5`? Also, why pick an example where `col2` is constant everywhere... Last, please give us the code to create `newData` (you can use `dput` for that) so as to make things easier for us.

Comment: Agree. Also, the do-something-by-group is well described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) and more recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593482/subtract-pairs-of-columns-based-on-matching-column/18593572#18593572). The examples can easily be extended to more than one grouping variable. Please see help pages for the functions mentioned in the two posts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the `merge` of two `aggregate`s:

```
out <- merge(aggregate(col3 ~ col1 + col2, mydf, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
             aggregate(cbind(col4, col5) ~ col1 + col2, 
                       mydf, `[`, 1, na.action = na.pass),
             by = c("col1", "col2"))
out <- cbind(id = 1:nrow(out), out)
out
#   id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# 1  1  200 2000  200  151 <NA>
# 2  2  201 2000  350  189 <NA>
```

The first `aggregate` takes the `mean` of "col3". The second `aggregate` extracts the first element of "col4" and "col5" respectively.

I've manually created an "id" column because in your example, the "id" column in the output doesn't seem to fit any discernible pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense, but here's an alternative

```
> cbind(aggregate(col3~col1+col2, data=newData, FUN="mean"),
        newData[!duplicated(newData[, "col1"]), c("col4", "col5")])
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  200 2000  200  151 <NA>
3  201 2000  350  189 <NA>
```