# How to calculate the mean of specific rows in R?

Tags: r, mean

I have a data file as following example but much more larger

```
names    num    Y1  Y2
William  1  4.71    7.4
William  2  3.75    8
William  3  4.71    7.9
Katja    1  5.83    8.5
Katja    2  5.17    7.1
Katja    3  6.08    7.4
Aroma    1  4.04    7.5
Aroma    2  5       6.9
Aroma    3  4.3     7.9
...
```

I have to calculate the mean for each 3 of the same names (first column) for Y1 and Y2. And then make a bar chart by the average of each name with Y1 and Y2, separately. So on the x axis I will have the names and on the y axis the mean. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What have you tried?

Comment: I am very new to r and tried to use mean but could not get anything out of it. How to use aggregate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `aggregate`. See `?aggregate` for further details.

```
> aggregate(.~names, FUN=mean, data=df[, -2])
    names       Y1       Y2
1   Aroma 4.446667 7.433333
2   Katja 5.693333 7.666667
3 William 4.390000 7.766667
```

[Take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593482/subtract-pairs-of-columns-based-on-matching-column/18593572#comment27363418_18593572) for another alternatives of taking mean for each group.

For the bar plots use R base `barplot` function although there other alternatives such as ggplot2 graphics.

```
barplot(DF[,2], names.arg=DF$names, ylab="mean of Y1", las=1) # for Y1
barplot(DF[,3], names.arg=DF$names, ylab="mean of Y2", las=1) # for Y2
```

which produce:

[image]

As you are very new to R, I recommend to read [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) which is a good starting point you to learn the basics of R.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `sqldf` package (assuming `df` is your table)

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT names, avg(Y1) as mean_Y1, avg(Y2) as mean_Y2 FROM df GROUP BY names")
```

Comment: It allows you to execute `SQL` queries on data frames. So broken down, the query is grouping your table by the names column, then extracting the name, the mean of Y1, and the mean of Y2.